# Gstreamer not working with Opencv when used inside Yocto Image on Jetson Nano

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, cross-compiling, yocto

Hi i am fairly new to the Gstreamer and Opencv, I am trying to run Gstreamer Pipeline inside Opencv code which will pass Frames collected by Gstreamer pass it to cv::VideoCapture and then pass it to cv::Mat then finally show frame in window on external display connected to jetson nano using cv::imshow

Camera Module: IMX219-170 Camera
Jetson Nano : Nvidia Jetson Nano Developer Kit (B01 4GB)

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstBus *bus;

    // Create the pipeline
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, format=YUY2, framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! appsink name=mysink", NULL);

    if (!pipeline) {
        g_printerr("Pipeline could not be created.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Start the pipeline
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    // Get the bus
    bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);

    // Retrieve the appsink element from the pipeline
    GstElement *appsink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "mysink");
    GstAppSink *appSink = GST_APP_SINK(appsink);

    // Variables for frame processing
    int width = 1920;
    int height = 1080;

    std::vector<cv::Mat> frames;  // Vector to store frames

    while (true) {
        // Wait for the next frame
        GstSample *sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appSink);
        GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
        GstMapInfo map;
        gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

        // Create an OpenCV Mat from the buffer data
        cv::Mat frame(cv::Size(width, height), CV_8UC2, map.data, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);

        // Convert YUY2 format to BGR
        cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2);

        // Process the frame using OpenCV
        // For example, you can perform operations such as resizing or applying filters

        frames.push_back(frame);  // Store the frame in the vector

        // Release the resources
        gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
        gst_sample_unref(sample);

        // Check for key press to exit the loop
        if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Free resources
    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    // Access the stored frames as needed
    for (const auto& frame : frames) {
        // Process or save the frames as desired
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it is failing to open camera

ive tried different Gstreamer Pipelines too as from here for H.264 : https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Jetson_Nano/Gstreamer/Example_Pipelines/Streaming